# Mysql SUM() vs PHP normal addition arithmetic

Tags: php, mysql, sum

In a program i'm working on, I have a table that shows how much time user spends working on each task. I'd like to display the grand total of the column `Time On Task`.

Since `tfoot` is outside of the while statement, I'm using a different query to calculate the grand total. This [Pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EbjrrB) represents how it looks like right now.

As  you can see, the problem is that `$grandtotal` does not equal the sum of all the `$tasktime`. How can I make this work?

Grand total query

```
$stots ="SELECT *,  SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(te.date_end, te.date_start)))) 
AS Duration FROM taskentries";
$resultots=mysqli_query($db,$stots);
$totaltime =mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultots);
$grandtotal = $totaltime['Duration'];
```

Table

```
    <table>
       <thead>
        <th>Task</th>
        <th>Date Start</th>
        <th>Date End</th>
        <th>Time On Task</th>
      </thead>
         <tfoot>
        <tr>
             <td th='Task'></td>
                <td th='Date Start'></td>
                <td th='Date End'>Grand Total</td>
                <td th=''>
                   <?php
          if($grandtotal < 0){
               echo '0';
          }else{
               echo $grandtotal;
          }?>

          </td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
      <tbody>

    <?php 
        $sql="SELECT * FROM taskentries";
         $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
         while($taskentry=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
         <tr>
             <td th='Task'><?=$taskentry['task'];?></td>
                <td th='Date Start'><?=$taskentry['date_start'];?></td>
                <td th='Date End'><?=$taskentry['date_end'];?></td>
                 <td th='Time On Task'>
                 <?php 
                 $date_start = date("h:i:sa",strtotime($taskentry['date_start']));
                 $date_end =  date("h:i:sa",strtotime($taskentry['date_end']));
                 $tasktime = $date_end - $date_start; 
                 if($tasktime < 0){
                 echo '0';
                 }else{
                 echo $tasktime;
                 }?>
                 </td>
         </tr>
       <?php };?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

In the PHP, you're setting `$date_start` and `$date_end` to strings like `"12:34:56am"`, and then subtracting them. Subtraction just works on numbers, it doesn't know anything about time, so a string like that is converted to the number `12`. So if you subtract "05:14:33" from "07:12:55", it will just return `2` because it's doing `7-5`. Also, when a number starts with `0` it's treated as octal, which only allows digits from `0` to `7`. So times that begin with `08:` or `09:` will be treated as `0`, because `8` and `9` are not valid digits.

`strtotime()` returns a timestamp, which is the number of seconds, you should just subtract those instead of calling `date()`. Then you can convert this to a time.

```
         $date_start = strtotime($taskentry['date_start']);
         $date_end =  strtotime($taskentry['date_end']);
         $tasktime = max(0, $date_end - $date_start); // don't show negative times
         echo date("H:i:s", $tasktime");
```

Note that `date()` is designed for printing converting to dates and times, not time durations. This won't give a correct answer if `$tasktime` is more than 24 hours. You should consider converting to `DateInterval`.

Comment: when doing `$total += $date_end - $date_start;` I get undefined variable `$total` if I remove the `+` the notice disappears. And the results of your code are integers. First row  is now 7200 and second row is 6406.

Comment: You need to initialize the variable to `0` before the loop.

Comment: Perhaps you should use the `DateInterval` class.

Comment: But you do understand what I'm trying to do right? The first query is for total of each row returned by the while() and the second query is for all rows which is displayed in tfoot.

Comment: By design tfoot is placed after thead above tbody.

Comment: Now the results im getting are first row 03:00:00  and second row 04:46:46 it does not add up to Mysql SUM() of 03:46:46

Comment: I thought you were asking about two different ways to get the total, one in PHP, the other in SQL.

Comment: I have edited my question to be more understandable with actual code so that you can visualize what I mean. Thanks

Comment: @Clark - Barmar is correct.  I'd recommend reading his answer carefully, and incorporating / trying his resolution.

Comment: @cale_b: but his solution does not work. Ive tried it.

Comment: I've updated the answer to match what you're actually trying to do now that I understand.